"Some of the eggs, she stashes away." (from documentary about a fox stealing the eggs of geese)
From a documentary, where fox takes the eggs of gees and gees trying to save them:

Some of the eggs, she stashes away. BBC - Fox and geese battle it out

I know that the regular sentence structure would be "She stashes away some of the eggs."
So, is putting the object at the beginning of the sentence a special usage for creating a more poetic or literary effect, or can we use it in our daily lives, too? For example:
"Mom, some of the eggs, I put in the lowest shelf of the fridge."

Yes, we can use it in our daily lives. It's completely normal.

The cakes, she ate; the potatoes, she left.

The inversion also emphasizes that the fox doesn't do the same thing with all of the eggs.  It isn't a "literary effect" in the sense that phrase is sometimes used, with the meaning "style without practical purpose".

Some of my mother-in-law’s cooking I actually liked.

@PaulTanenbaum - I knew a curate who said 'Some of the egg, I liked'.

Cambridge Dictionary explains
word order and focus:

... to emphasise a particular part of the clause, we can change the typical order. An untypical word order in a declarative clause, for example, is object – subject – verb (OSV).


A: Have you decided what colour to paint the kitchen yet?


B: The kitchen we’ve already painted. We decided on white for now.  We still can’t decide on the colour for the living room.

Here B uses OSV to focus on the kitchen rather than the topic on colours.
This method gives the same effect in the OP's two examples; the descriptions apply to only some of the eggs, not all.
